# Unit test in Laravel9 is failing

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

Ok so I've been creating unit tests for my routes in my app. I have a test which I can't get to pass.

```php
public function test_client_save_access_if_authorised()
{
    $this->seed(TestSeederBase::class);
    $user = User::find(1);

    $response = $this->actingAs($user, 'web')
        ->withSession(['banned' => false])
        ->post('/client/save', [
            'csrf_token' => csrf_token(),
            'id' => 1,
            'title' => 'Test Title',
            'contact_1_title' => 'Another Title',
            'contact_1_email' => 'cas@example.com',
            'contact_1_phone_number' => '01234567890',
        ]);

    $response->dumpHeaders();

    $response->dumpSession();

    $response->dump();

    $response->assertStatus(200);

    $task = JobWorkItem::where('job_number', 1)
        ->where('user_id', 1)
        ->first();

    $this->assertSame(1, $task->job_number);
}
```

When this runs it fails with the assertStatus(200) line (I get a 302)

the code ran by this test is:

```php
/**
 * @param ClientRequest $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
 */
public function store( ClientRequest $request )
{
    $is_enabled = 0;
    if (isset($request->is_enabled) && $request->is_enabled === 'on') {
        $is_enabled = 1;
    }

    $client = Client::find($request->id);
    $client->is_enabled = $is_enabled;
    $client->title = $request->title;

    $client->save();

    // We need to get all contacts so we can build the request string
    $all = ClientContact::where('client_id', $request->id)->get();
    foreach ($all as $cc) {
        if (isset($request->{'contact_' . $cc->id . '_title'})) {
            $title = $request->{'contact_' . $cc->id . '_title'};
            $email = $request->{'contact_' . $cc->id . '_email'};
            $phone = $request->{'contact_' . $cc->id . '_phone_number'};
            if ($title === '-' || $title === '') {
                $cc->forceDelete();
            } else {
                $cc->title = $title;
                $cc->email = $email;
                $cc->phone_number = $phone;
                $cc->save();
            }
        }
    }

    return back();
}
```

The full response after adding the $response dump lines is as follows:

```
/bin/php -c /etc/php/8.1/apache2/php.ini /hdd/projects/laravel.jobadmin.ecl/htdocs/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --bootstrap /hdd/projects/laravel.jobadmin.ecl/htdocs/bootstrap/app.php --configuration /hdd/projects/laravel.jobadmin.ecl/htdocs/phpunit.xml --filter "/(Tests\\Eclipse\\Routes\\WebRoutesTest::test_client_save_access_if_authorised)( .*)?$/" --test-suffix WebRoutesTest.php /hdd/projects/laravel.jobadmin.ecl/htdocs/tests/Eclipse/Routes --teamcity
Testing started at 13:00 ...
PHPUnit 9.5.24 #StandWithUkraine

]8;;file:///hdd/projects/laravel.jobadmin.ecl/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Testing/TestResponse.php#L1520\^]8;;\ array:5 [
  "cache-control" => array:1 [
    0 => "no-cache, private"
  ]
  "date" => array:1 [
    0 => "Mon, 12 Sep 2022 12:00:35 GMT"
  ]
  "location" => array:1 [
    0 => "https://laravel.jobadmin.ecl"
  ]
  "content-type" => array:1 [
    0 => "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
  ]
  "set-cookie" => array:2 [
    0 => "XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6ImYxZGpOc09TQzQzdzFsOUkxdEszakE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiTlk3U2FuVXNvK0tvd0orZUJmcnlQcGw5MGlxejRxNnM1dkY0UXJDMXBPNjgzckpQaDg1aldwMFRidnQ3VGtXRm9Db1pHUS9xTnFXQ2xBZ2hVWWhqVDZKSVE2ekFVeVVRSEVPcEJvZFVFZFZ1WURqNFcwMGFjc0xlSDlGV2E5Q1MiLCJtYWMiOiI4Yjg5ZGE4YmVmZTVhOGVlODNjZTEwOWExOTI3Y2Y4ZTlmNjBkM2I5YWQ3ZjBjNWJjYjA3ZTdiYjQ4ZTAyZWVkIiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D; expires=Mon, 12 Sep 2022 14:00:35 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; domain=laravel.jobadmin.ecl; samesite=lax"
    1 => "jobadmindev_session=eyJpdiI6Ik5BWFZvZVJUdFY2WG9qZ2s2OUFUM3c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiT0t2aUlJOVFLb2RQcXV4QnluWXVwd0JTTmp3NmVmYnpKOW5VZTAvYkpFd1E5aEpyRGNWM0o4cVJHTEFMbCttUURjUThoMXBTQWpTUndTWVIxYVloYWo5b2RuTTFRclArUk9NMjllTTh0V2NvZEJKWjlMNktaZ2dldmZTMkxQck4iLCJtYWMiOiJhZWZlZmVmOWY4MDVhMzAxMTQxMDNlMDFkZjAxYjkzNWMyMDkzOGYwMTMzZmY0NWQ1MjliZmJhODFiMWJhNDIwIiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D; expires=Mon, 12 Sep 2022 14:00:35 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; domain=laravel.jobadmin.ecl; httponly; samesite=lax"
  ]
]
]8;;file:///hdd/projects/laravel.jobadmin.ecl/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Testing/TestResponse.php#L1536\^]8;;\ array:4 [
  "_token" => "osEZV5Vd06rR9GPEx5XIxyFoN9oCoU7z1JMpvybf"
  "banned" => false
  "password_hash_web" => "$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi"
  "_flash" => array:2 [
    "old" => []
    "new" => []
  ]
]
]8;;file:///hdd/projects/laravel.jobadmin.ecl/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Testing/TestResponse.php#L1507\^]8;;\ """
<!DOCTYPE html>\n
<html>\n
    <head>\n
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />\n
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='https://laravel.jobadmin.ecl'" />\n
\n
        <title>Redirecting to https://laravel.jobadmin.ecl</title>\n
    </head>\n
    <body>\n
        Redirecting to <a href="https://laravel.jobadmin.ecl">https://laravel.jobadmin.ecl</a>.\n
    </body>\n
</html>
"""

Expected response status code [200] but received 302.
Failed asserting that 200 is identical to 302.
 /hdd/projects/laravel.jobadmin.ecl/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Testing/TestResponse.php:179
 /hdd/projects/laravel.jobadmin.ecl/htdocs/tests/Eclipse/Routes/WebRoutesTest.php:417
 


Time: 00:00.321, Memory: 44.50 MB


FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any ideas how to pass this one? The result of the test is it is failing with a status 302 and not the 200 I expected.

An update: The function is running and the data is saved as expected. My function has a redirect back and I think this is my issue? How can I test this to be the case?

Comment: Is the validation being performed in your `ClientRequest` failing by any chance?

Comment: Thats a good point! I'll check.

Comment: Sadly I only validate the title and it is present and passes the requirements for it. (between 3 and 64 chars)

Comment: Have you attached a debugger or tried a diedump statement inside your store method when running the test to confirm is even executing?

Comment: Check your middlewares, you are either not getting logged in or something like that, also you don't need to pass a `csrf` token on the test, that is ignored, and you should assert using `$this->assertDatabaseHas`, not get the result and do `assertSame`

Comment: @Peppermintology, yes I have a debugger. All values are saved. I'm thinking that my issue might be due to the redirect back as the return

Comment: Ah yes, I didn’t notice that and you’re right it is most likely the culprit.